# E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 64, mPlayer(0xaf149260) when using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, playback

I've been trying to play and stop an mp3 file using a play and stop buttons, but it keeps giving out this error:

> E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 64, mPlayer(0xaf149260)
>   E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
>   E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

This is the code that I've got so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final MediaPlayer mainSongMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_copy);

        Button playButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        Button stopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mainSongMP.start();
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainSongMP.stop();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should refer to the MediaPlayer state diagram:

[image: MediaPlayer state diagram]

After calling stop, you cannot enter directly into the Started state again. You need to either prepare the MediaPlayer again, or release it and start over.

Answer (score -2):

just use like this

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                    mainSongMP.start();
                }
            });
    
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                    mainSongMP.pause();
                }
            });
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted as **not useful**. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29034489)